# Multilevel click submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation, submenu

i want a submenu with 3 levels.

At first only the main points (men1, men2) should be displayed. Then with click on "men1" "men1.1 and men 1.2" should become visible. When clicking on "men1.2" "men1.2.1, men1.2.2 and men 1.2.3" should become visible the rest should stay invisivle

When Clicking on "men2" all other sub's should disapear and only "men2.1 and men2.2" are visible.

I hope you understand what i mean! In the end everything should be animated like expanding ore something!

this is my progress so far

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#navi ul').click(function(){
    $('#navi').find('.sub1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).find('.sub1').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });
  $('#navi ul ul').click(function(){
    $('#navi').find('.sub2').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).find('.sub2').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
font-size: 2em;
padding:1em 0 0 0;
}

.sub1 {
    font-size:0.7em;
    padding:0 0 0 1em;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sub2 {
    font-size:0.7em;
    padding:0.2em 0 1em 2em;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navi">
  <ul class="main">
    <li><a >men1</a>
      <ul class="sub1">
        <li><a >men1.1</a>
          <ul class="sub2">
            <li><a >men1.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a >men1.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a >men1.1.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a >men1.2</a>
          <ul class="sub2">
            <li><a >men1.2.1</a></li>
            <li><a >men1.2.2</a></li>
            <li><a >men1.2.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="main">
    <li><a >men2</a>
      <ul class="sub1">
        <li><a >men2.1</a>
          <ul class="sub2">
            <li><a >men2.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a >men2.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a >men2.1.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a >men2.2</a>
          <ul class="sub2">
            <li><a >men2.2.1</a></li>
            <li><a >men2.2.2</a></li>
            <li><a >m2n2.2.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see level 3 is not disappearing when clicking on level 1.
I would prefer jquery solutions because I am learning and it would be easier for me to understand the solution.

Hope you can help me!! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're probably going to want to use `show()` and `hide()` rather than CSS visibility to avoid the blank spaces in your menu.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to stop propagation on the third-level elements to prevent clicks from triggering parent elements:

```
.sub1 {
    display: none;
}
.sub2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Notice the change to CSS to eliminate empty space in the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navi > ul > li').click(function () {
        $('#navi .sub1').not( $(this).find('.sub1') ).hide();
        $(this).find('.sub1').toggle();
    });
    $('#navi > ul ul > li').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#navi .sub2').not( $(this).find('.sub2') ).hide();
        $(this).find('.sub2').toggle();
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/d8wm0cok/)

You also mentioned slide effects. Here's [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/d8wm0cok/1/) with that in place.

Comment: Thank you for that fast solution! I just recognized that when i click on a level 3 submenu (for example men1.1.1) then the level 3 is disappearing.

Comment: Yep. You'll have to work in `stopPropagation()`, `preventDefault()`, or whatever is appropriate, depending on what those items end up being.

Comment: Oh ok now i need to learn what these do. They are the navigation for the bxslider. When i click on men1.1 level 3 is opening but when i click again on men1.1 then level 3 should not disappear. also level 3 should not disappear when i click on it